# Can anyone tell me why the linked list is displaying garbage value after inserting a new node at the end?

Tags: c, linked-list, garbage

I am having issues displaying the linked list values. The display function seems to work fine... until I insert a new node at the end. I spent a good amount of time trying to resolve the issue, but nothing seems to work. It just keeps displaying garbage value.

My C source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n = 0;

typedef struct Student
{
    char name[50];
    int roll;
    struct Student *next;
} st;

void createList(st *head)
{
    st *p;
    p = head;
    int i = 0;
    char x = ' ';

    printf("Enter number of nodes: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%c", &x);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        gets(head->name);
        printf("Enter roll number: ");
        scanf("%d", &(head->roll));
        scanf("%c", &x);
        
        head->next = (st *)malloc(sizeof(st));

        head = head->next;
    }

    head->next = NULL;
}

void display(st *head)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (head->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("\nName\t\t:\t%s", head->name);
        printf("\nRoll no.\t:\t%d", head->roll);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

void insertEnd(st *head)
{
    st *p, *newnode;
    p = head;
    char x = ' ';

    newnode = (st *)malloc(sizeof(st));
    printf("Enter name: ");
    gets(newnode->name);
    printf("Enter roll no.: ");
    scanf("%d", &(newnode->roll));
    scanf("%c", &x);
    newnode->next = NULL;
    
    while (p->next != NULL)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->next = newnode;
}

int main()
{
    st *head;
    head = (st *)malloc(sizeof(st));
    createList(head);

    printf("The data entered:\n");
    display(head);
    
    printf("\nInsert data for newnode at the end:\n");
    insertEnd(head);
    
    printf("The data after insertion:\n");
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Enter number of nodes: 3
Enter name: Alpha
Enter roll number: 100
Enter name: Beta
Enter roll number: 200
Enter name: Gamma
Enter roll number: 300
The data entered:

Name            :       Alpha
Roll no.        :       100
Name            :       Beta
Roll no.        :       200
Name            :       Gamma
Roll no.        :       300
Insert data for newnode at the end:
Enter name: Delta
Enter roll no.: 400
The data after insertion:

Name            :       Alpha
Roll no.        :       100
Name            :       Beta
Roll no.        :       200
Name            :       Gamma
Roll no.        :       300
Name            :       peÅf╡☺
Roll no.        :       1986622020
```

As you can see in the output of the code, the linked list display works fine until I add a new node at the end. I watched a couple of tutorials, and I don't see anything wrong with my code. Please help my find the issue, I am new to linked lists.

Comment: `head->next = (st *)malloc(sizeof(st));` That leaves an unintalised node at the end of the list. Suggest you allocate nodes as they are needed instead of trying to allocate one ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing out tweaks to your code prior to seeing the above comment from "kaylum", but that basically answers the issue. Following is a revision of your code that happens to implement the ideas mapped out in kaylum's comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n=0;

typedef struct Student
{
    char name[50];
    int roll;
    struct Student *next;
} st;

void createList(st *head)
{
    st *p;
    p = head;
    int i = 0;
    char x = ' ';

    printf("Enter number of nodes: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%c", &x);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        gets(head->name);
        printf("Enter roll number: ");
        scanf("%d", &(head->roll));
        scanf("%c", &x);

        if (i == n)                     /* Condition the update of the next node along with allocating more memory */
        {
            head->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            head->next = (st *)malloc(sizeof(st));
            head = head->next;
        }                               /* End of the tweaks */
    }

    head->next = NULL;
}

void display(st *head)
{
    int i=0;

    while(head != NULL)     /* This provides a complete list and reacts to the other revision made to the program */
    {
        printf("\nName\t\t:\t%s",head->name);
        printf("\nRoll no.\t:\t%d", head->roll);
        printf("Pointer: %p\n", head);
        printf("Next node: %p\n", head->next);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
void insertEnd(st* head)
{
    st *p, *newnode;
    p = head;
    char x = ' ';

    newnode = (st*)malloc(sizeof(st));
    printf("Enter name: ");
    gets(newnode->name);
    printf("Enter roll no.: ");
    scanf("%d", &(newnode->roll));
    scanf("%c", &x);
    newnode->next = NULL;

    while (p->next != NULL)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->next = newnode;

}

int main()
{
    st *head;
    head = (st *)malloc(sizeof(st));
    createList(head);

    printf("The data entered:\n");
    display(head);

    printf("\nInsert data for newnode at the end:\n");
    insertEnd(head);

    printf("The data after insertion:\n");
    display(head);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Adding in the "if" block to condition the "malloc" request eliminates the dangling memory allocation and properly sets the "next" pointer value.  Also, I tweaked the "while" test in the display function to go along with the tweak in the creation function.

Answer (score 0):

The program does not handle lists in a consusten way:

- the empty list `head` actually points to an uninitialized allocated node.
- `createList` sets the data of this node and allocates a new uninitialized node after it, so the last node in the list is always uninitialized, hence contains random data.
- `insertEnd` enumerates the list nodes until it finds the last one and links the newly allocated and initialized to its `next` pointer.  The problem is the *last* node in the list is uninititialized so its `next` pointer could be anything and the line `p = p->next` makes `p` an uninitialized pointer, dereferencing it has undefined behavior.  The code could crash, the random data output for this node in `display()` is another side effect of undefined behavior.

You should change the logic of the code:

- an empty list is just a null pointer.
- `createList` should return a pointer to the head of the allocated list.
- the nodes in the list should always be initialized with proper content and a valid `next` pointer.
- `insertEnd` should take a pointer to the head node to update it if the list is empty.
- you should not use `gets()`
- the extra `scanf("%c", &x)` is an attempt at reading the pending newline, you should instead write a `flushInput()` function that reads bytes from `stdin` until a newline is read of end of file is reached.
- you should avoid mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()` from the same stream.
- you should always test the return value of `scanf()` to detect and report invalid or missing input.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Student {
    char name[50];
    int roll;
    struct Student *next;
} Student;

int flushInput(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

Student *newStudent(void) {
    Student *p = calloc(sizeof(*p), 1);
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("cannot allocate Student node\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("Enter name: ");
    if (scanf(" %49[^\n]", p->name) == 1) {
        flushInput();
        printf("Enter roll number: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &p->roll) == 1) {
            flushInput();
            return p;
        }
    }
    flushInput();
    printf("Invalid input\n");
    free(p);
    return NULL;
}

Student *createList(void) {

    printf("Enter number of nodes: ");
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        flushInput();
        return NULL;
    }

    flushInput();

    Student *head = NULL;
    Student *last = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Student *p = newStudent();
        if (last) {
            last->next = p;
        } else {
            head = p;
        }
        last = p;
    }
    return head;
}

void display(const Student *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("Name\t\t:\t%s\n", head->name);
        printf("Roll no.\t:\t%d\n", head->roll);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void insertEnd(Student **headp) {
    Student *newnode = newStudent();
    if (newnode) {
        if (*headp == NULL) {
            *headp = newnode;
        } else {
            Student *p;
            for (p = *headp; p->next; p = p->next)
                continue;
            p->next = newnode;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    Student *head = createList();

    printf("The data entered:\n");
    display(head);

    printf("Insert data for newnode at the end:\n");
    insertEnd(&head);

    printf("The data after insertion:\n");
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```